# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'persona.denominacion' in 'field list'

Tags: laravel, eloquent

requiero de su ayuda, verán, tengo 2 tablas trabajador (id, idpersona) y persona (id, denominacion); en un proyecto de laravel tengo ambos modelos de la siguiente forma:

Modelo para tabla persona

```
class PersonaModel extends Model
{
}
```

Modelo para tabla trabajador

```
class TrabajadorModel extends Model
{
    public function persona() {
        return $this->belongsTo(PersonaModel::class, 'idpersona');
    }
}
```

Estoy usando relationship para unir ambas tablas, ahora en mi controlador trabajador deseo mostrar las columnas especificas de todos los registros que cumplan con una condición de la tabla persona, estoy usando esta instrucción.

```
return TrabajadorModel::whereHas('persona', function($query){
    $query->where('denominacion', 'like', "%{$mivariable}%");
})->get();
```

Lo que me retorna esto:

```
[{"id":180,"idpersona":1},{"id":130,"idpersona":13},{"id":23,"idpersona":42}]
```

Es decir que me retorna los registros que si cumplen con la condición que requiero, pero el problema viene ahora => **que yo deseo mostrar en el resultado el valor denominacion de la tabla persona**.

Haciendo el siguiente cambio puedo seleccionar que campos me retornara la cosulta, sin embargo solo funciona con los campos de la tabla principal (es decir trabajador).

```
return TrabajadorModel::whereHas('persona', function($query){
    $query->where('denominacion', 'like', "%{$mivariable}%");
})->select('id')->get();
```

Este es el resultado:

```
[{"id":180},{"id":130}]
```

Pero si agrego persona.denominacion:

```
return TrabajadorModel::whereHas('persona', function($query){
    $query->where('denominacion', 'like', "%{$mivariable}%");
})->select('id','persona.denominacion')->get();
```

Me salta el siguiente error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'persona.denominacion' in 'field list' (SQL: select `id`, `persona`.`denominacion` from `trabajador` where exists (select * from `persona` where `trabajador`.`idpersona` = `persona`.`id` and `denominacion` like %prueba%))
```

Entonces, la pregunta es:

¿ Como hago para que mi resultado muestre los campos *trabajador.id*, *persona.denominacion* ?

Para que el resultado sea el siguiente:

```
[{"id":180,"denominacion":"juan carlos"},{"id":130,"denominacion":"silvia mercedes"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

La propiedad denominación no pertenece al modelo TrabajadorModel por lo tanto debe ser accedida por medio del método que has definido con el nombre de: persona el cual te identifica la relación.

Entonces debes:

- Encadenar el método with al cual vas a indicar dentro de un vector asociativo la clave que es la relación y el valor será la función anónima la cual te va a permitir establecer el select de forma interna

Y por fuera a nivel de la consulta principal en el otro select solo dejas la invocación a la propiedad id del modelo TrabajadorModel.

Por otro lado debes incluir:

- En el `select` interno la llave primaria de la relación
- En el `select` externo la llave foránea que te vincula al modelo con la relación definida

Prueba así:

```
return TrabajadorModel::whereHas('persona', function($query){
            $query->where('denominacion', 'like', "%{$mivariable}%");
        })->with(['persona' => function($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'persona.denominacion');
        }])->select('id', 'idpersona')->get();
```